# How to populated selected columns in GridView and update from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView1`, which I am binding from code behind. The one of the columns in the `GridView` depends on `Label1.Text` as follows:

```
SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location_Profile_Name, " + Label1.Text + " FROM Home_Profile_Master", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

The aspx code for the same is :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location_Profile_Name" 
SortExpression="Location_Profile_Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("Location_Profile_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Home_Profile" SortExpression="Label10">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Profile") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_Profile") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I am getting an error in the aspx page as: **DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Home_Profile'**.

I am not able to figure out what the mistake is. Kindly Help...! thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about this `SqlCommand("SELECT Location_Profile_Name, " + Label1.Text + " FROM Home_Profile_Master", con);` ?  Can't `Label1.Text` go rough? :)

Comment: Yeah based on `Label1.Text` is another data cloumn which I want to populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed 'Home_Profile' in the query.

```
SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location_Profile_Name," + Label1.Text + " as Home_Profile FROM Home_Profile_Master", con);
```

Comment: Won't this generate 3 columns in my Grid?

Comment: It says invalid column name Home_Profile. And I dont have Home_Profile column in database

Comment: It won't generate three columns in your gridView as you have explicitly declared Item Template and it yhat you have mentioned '<%# Bind("Home_Profile") %>' but you are not providing data to that column from your query

Comment: Oh then in my template should I replace Home_Profile to Label1??

Comment: ok..then what is Label1.Text? you acn name it as follow...SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location_Profile_Name," + Label1.Text + " as Home_Profile FROM Home_Profile_Master", con);

Answer (score 1):

you shuld have Home_Profile column in data table try this

```
 SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Location_Profile_Name,Home_Profile, " + Label1.Text + " FROM Home_Profile_Master", con);
```

Comment: Won't this generate 3 columns in my Grid?

Comment: It says invalid column name Home_Profile. And I dont have Home_Profile column in database